# What does Bede's phrase, "suae genti ducatum praebebat, obtinuit," mean?

Tags: meaning, medieval-latin, beda

In Bede's [*Ecclesiastical History*, 2.5](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bede/bede2.shtml), there's a phrase that appears to be the subject of some debate:

> Nam primus imperium huiusmodi Aelli rex Australium Saxonum; secundus Caelin rex Occidentalium Saxonum, qui lingua ipsorum Ceaulin uocabatur; tertius, ut diximus, Aedilberct rex Cantuariorum; quartus Reduald rex Orientalium Anglorum, **qui etiam uiuente Aedilbercto eidem suae genti ducatum praebebat, obtinuit**; quintus Aeduini rex Nordanhymbrorum gentis...

My copy ([Oxford, 1999](https://books.google.com/books?id=egy-k7LV-e4C&pg=PA78)), translated by Colgrave, renders the bolded phrase as:

> who even during the lifetime of Æthelberht was gaining the leadership for his own race

But that's quite different from [L. C. Jane's translation](http://legacy.fordham.edu/halsall/basis/bede-book2.asp):

> who, whilst Ethelbert lived, had been subservient to him

The note in my copy reads:

> Various translations have been suggested, each altering its significance.  What it seems to be saying is that Rædwald obtained independent rule over his own people, the East Angles, even during the lifetime of Æthelberht of Kent.  It is notable that the author of the Anglo-Saxon translation of *EH* was equally perplexed, and omitted the entire phrase.

Is this a reasonable interpretation?  What is it about this phrase that makes it so difficult to interpret?

Comment: I think the issue with translation has a lot to do with the complexity allowed by Latin grammar, not always paralelled by modern languages. Being no grammar expert, I see quite a complex relative clause, with two (arguabliy three) verbs: you either translate it as more than one sentence, or agree to loose meaning.

Comment: I think *obtinuit* isn't part of this phrase at all, but is the main verb of the sentence (taking the various kings as subjects and *imperium* as object). Colgrave's translation makes sense to me; Jane's doesn't, because it overlooks *etiam* and because while Athelbert reigned it would not make sense for anyone to "offer/provide the leadership" to him.

Comment: I see it like this: Reduald obtained something -what? -Ducatum -which one? -the same one he was pursuing for his people (eidem suae genti) -when was he pursuing it? -of course at the time he obtained it, but also he was already pursuing it when Aedilberct was alive.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, here is how I see the passage.

One interpretation is to to assume that *eidem* refers to Aedilberct.
Then one reads *suae genti ducatum* as "the leadership of his people".
It is this leadership that he offered to Aedilberct: *ille ducatum eidem Aedilbercto praebebat*.
This means being subordinate to Aedilberct.
This approach has severe problems: The word *obtinuit* makes little sense and one would expect *suae genti**s** ducatum* instead of the dative.
I don't know if any of the translators thought this way.

Because of these issues I would consider *eidem* to modify *suae genti*, but that feels a bit fishy, too.
It could also be that *eidem* refers to Reduald, but I would have expected *sibi* instead.

It seems to me that *praebebat* and *obtinuit* have the same object, *ducatum*.
It makes sense that Reduald obtained leadership, but it is a weird combination that he would also offer it.
I see two ways around this:
Perhaps he offered leadership to his people and then obtained it; the people recognized him as their leader.
Or perhaps *praebere* does not mean "to offer" but "acquire" (my Finnish–Latin–Finnish dictionary offers such an option); he tried to gain power for his people and succeeded.

No matter which way I approach the passage, it sounds fishy.
The difficulty seems to boil down to two questions:
What does *praebere* mean here?
And, more importantly, what does *eidem* refer to?

**Added:**
Thanks to comments from TKR, I have refined my opinion.
First, *obtinuit* is the predicate of the sentence *Nam primus imperium huiusmodi Aelli rex Australium Saxonum … obtinuit*.
It is unrelated to the rest of the boldface passage.
Second, *eidem* seems to refer Reduald's own people (the people last mentioned, *Orientales Angli*).
I still feel a bit uneasy about this, since *eidem* and *suae* express almost the same thing and this combination feels somehow wrong.
Other explanations make less sense, so I see it just as a way of adding emphasis.
This brings me essentially to Colgrave's translation, so I will not give a new translation.

Comment: *Eidem suae genti* going together makes good sense to me. *Eidem* here would mean "the same one just mentioned": "the king of the East Angles, who was acquiring the primacy *for that same people* even while A. was alive..." As for *obtinuit*, I think it's outside the clause -- see my comment above.

Comment: @TKR, I now see what *obtinuit* does, and things make more sense. Regarding *eidem*, do you mean that *suae* means Aedilberct's? I originally read it as referring to Reduald, but the other people makes more sense after a fresh reading.

Comment: No, I think it does mean "Reduald's own people". I don't see how it can refer to Aedilberct, since it's reflexive.

Comment: @TKR, hmm... Does *eidem* add anything to *suae*, then? I'm ok with redundancy in general, but this feels somehow wrong to me. (Side note: Did you really mean West Angles instead of East Angles in your first comment? I can edit old comments if needed.)

Comment: Oops, I did mean East Angles, you're right. I think *eidem* adds the sense "the same one that was just mentioned" -- it's not strictly necessary from an informational standpoint, but I don't think it's unusual from a narrative one.

Comment: @TKR, ok, now I think I fully understand what you are saying. I will try to remember to work these new insights into the answer tomorrow. Thanks! (I edited the first comment.)

Answer (score 3):

My Latin is poor, so this is only guesswork too long to suggest in comments. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can confirm my guesses here or correct my errors.

### “obtinuit”

[Elsewhere in similar historical records](http://bit.ly/1P9xGm3), **obtinuit** seems to mean "took office", as in chronologies of who served as bishop or archdeacon at a certain place, etc. For example, *Prioratum obtinuit anno 1478*: he became Prior in 1478. The verb *obtineo* suggests receiving something that already exists, and indeed in the small sampling of these chronologies that I looked at, this verb seems to appear often in sequences, describing the continuity of a single office as a succession of different people hold it. In many instances, *obtinuit* combines with *ab* to indicate who appointed the person to the office; e.g. the office was "obtained from" the Pope. I've also seen *tradidit* ("handed on").

If that is correct, then **imperium obtinuit** means "obtained the realm", that is, took over as ruler of all the kingdoms—became a sort of emperor. Some cursory googling suggests that this is indeed a common way of putting it. If so, then *ducatum* is not the object of *obtinuit*.

### “ducatum”

Many of the names of the medieval offices that go with *obtinuit* seem to end in *-atum*, which I'm guessing is cognate with English *-ate* in the same contexts. For example, *Archidiaconatum obtinuit* = he became archdeacon.  *Decanatum obtinuit* = he became dean, though I'm less sure of this one. Note that in English we usually say "became archdeacon", but the Latin literally translated is "obtained the Archdeaconate".

Following that analogy, in this context **ducatum** might specifically mean "the Dukeship" or "a Dukedom" rather than leadership in general. See [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=kWdHAAAAYAAJ&dq=obtinuit&pg=PA330#v=snippet&q=ducatum&f=false) for other instances of *ducatum* in similar records.

### Translation

So, paring down the sentence, this:

> Quartus Reduald rex Orientalium Anglorum, qui etiam uiuente Aedilbercto eidem suae genti ducatum praebebat, [imperium] obtinuit.

would mean:

> 1. Rædwald, king of the East Angles, became the fourth to hold rule over all the Anglo-Saxon kingdoms. Even while the previous such ruler, Æthelberht, was still alive, Rædwald **granted a dukedom** (or granted independence) to his (Æthelberht's) people.

A problem with this translation is that **suae** is reflexive and Rædwald is the subject. Possibly, though, Bede intended the apparently redundant **eidem suae genti** (to his own same people) to relocate the referent of **suae** to Æthelberht. This would agree with **etiam**, since the passage would point out something unexpected.

The big question is: did Æthelberht lose the imperium while he was still alive? If so, then the sentence by Bede would mean that Rædwald took the imperium while Æthelberht was still alive and gave the Kentish people some kind of official status as an autonomous dukedom.  [This chronology](http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/KingListsBritain/EnglandBretwaldas.htm) says that when Rædwald took the imperium, he did not control Kent, viewing it instead as a peer. So perhaps in this sense, he granted Kent **ducatum**, meaning autonomy, self-leadership (only a guess of mine).

If **suae** is Rædwald, then in order to make sense, you'd probably have to interpret **ducatum** as leadership, as in Colgrave's interpretation, with the somewhat hazy implication that the East Angles were moving up in the world during Æthelberht's lifetime:

> 2. Rædwald, king of the East Angles,  became the fourth to hold rule over all the Anglo-Saxon kingdoms. Even while the previous such ruler, Æthelberht, was still alive, Rædwald **provided leadership** to his (own) people.

By the way, notice that Æthelberht is called *rex Cantuariorum,* not *rex Cantiæ,* that is, king of the Kentish People, not king of Kent. This seems to agree with *genti.* However, the same applies to *Orientalium Anglorum,* so this doesn't help resolve the ambiguity.

Finally, note that **praebebat** is imperfect. My first translation above would fit a lot better with the perfect tense. The imperfect tense suggests the second reading, but I'm not aware of **praebere** being used in that sense. (That sense might have plenty of currency; I'm just not familiar enough with the literature to know. Can anyone here point out an interesting source?) So, for now, I'm favoring the first translation: Rædwald did not conquer Kent, even as he assumed the imperium from Æthelberht.

### Why so ambiguous?

As for *why* the passage is so ambiguous, there seem to be several different ways to hook up the grammar and sense, none of which is fully satisfactory. Simon Keynes goes over several interpretations in "[Rædwald the Bretwalda](https://books.google.com/books?id=Nq5MuuiZxdYC&lpg=PA106&ots=DaSRcQYzea&dq=%22eidem%20suae%20genti%22&pg=PA106#v=onepage&q=%22eidem%20suae%20genti%22&f=false)". It seems strange to say that Rædwald "supplied leadership" to his own people; isn't that what kings normally do? Why **etiam**, then, which suggests something beyond expectation? It might make sense to say that Rædwald offered Æthelberht leadership of the East Angles, but that would be **ducatum suae gentis**. **Ducatum** seems like it's there to contrast with **imperium**: it's a smaller sort of imperium. "Rædwald was leading his people's advancement during Æthelberht's imperium" (Colgrave's interpretation) violates common usage of **praebebat**. My translation #1 (originally proposed by Hanna Vollrath-Reichelt in 1971) seems to violate common usage of **suae**.

The trouble might actually result not from the grammar as much as from the ambiguous nature of the **imperium** itself. If the **imperium** is something vague, like a tendency on the part of leaders on the Continent to write to you when they want to address all the Anglo-Saxons through one person, but does not imply military supremacy or recognition at home, then it won't agree with modern expectations about hierarchical relations among leaders. Æthelberht might be [bretwalda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretwalda) but at the same time he might sometimes be subservient to Rædwald; the situation changes continually as battles are won and alliances shift.

The imperium also violates the expectation that a ruler is ruler for life and that these rulers were consecutive with no long gaps between them. For example, [Ceawlin's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceawlin_of_Wessex#Bretwaldaship) says there was an approximately 50–year gap between Ælle and Ceawlin, and mentions that even during his bretwaldaship, Ceawlin often lost control of some of the kingdoms. The [chronology mentioned above](http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/KingListsBritain/EnglandBretwaldas.htm) suggests that Æthelberht's failure to broker an agreement between the Roman Church and the Celtic Church around 603 damaged his credibility as bretwalda. Rædwald became bretwalda in 616, so there may have been another long gap.

The passage *might* even be Bede's way of saying that holding the Anglo-Saxon imperium doesn't necessarily mean that you were the top dog always and everywhere. And then again, it might just be a transcription error, as suggested by Henry Hallam [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=8sJeAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22eidem%20suae%20genti%22%20transposition&pg=PA248#v=onepage&q=%22eidem%20suae%20genti%22%20transposition&f=false).

Comment: Oops, TKR's [comment elsewhere](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/970/what-does-bedes-phrase-suae-genti-ducatum-praebebat-obtinuit-mean#comment2079_971) just reminded me that _suae_ is only reflexive. That pretty well knocks out my first translation. Now my only doubt about the second translation (which is about the same as Colgrave's) is whether there is precedent for _praebeo_ meaning "demonstrates a quality". Or perhaps the meaning is comparable to "won independence for his people".

Comment: Well, after thinking and browsing Google Scholar some more, I think it's not out of the question that _suae_ refers to Æthelberht. I've updated the answer with more tidbits.

Answer (score 3):

I praise the scholar effort of Ben and Joonas.

Even though I feel I am not even close to give such a thorough answer, I think I can add some complementary insights. Particularly, I'd start with the last question, which seems to me -correct my if I am wrong- as an important part of the concern:

> What is it about this phrase that makes it so difficult to interpret?

I think the point has become clear that there is some **ambiguity** in the construction, especially: which role are both verbs playing and to whom is the reflexive *reflecting*.

It must not be ignored that Latin allows for intricate, even recursive, relative clauses. In fact there are plenty of examples of written Latin sentences that simply cannot be translated as just one into modern languages. This special *freedom* is not exempt of greater risks of ambiguity.

IMHO, the fact that most of us are not 100% certain of what the author really meant (not even the translators agree) is nothing but evidence of such ambiguity. (*Moreover, I see some advantage in not assuming that just* every *sentence that has been preserved from historic times is free of **error***, even grammatical ones).

Some additional ideas:

1. Although I agree that the **reflexive** may be intended to either Æthelberht or Rædwald, I see *qui* in nominative while *eidem* in dative, and can't help but think that *suae* means *Redualdi*. I ignore whether, as suggested in the comments, it could be some grammatical feature particular to medieval Latin, or whether I am wrong with this notion.
2. Regarding the verbal form **obtinuit**, I do not see alternatives to it being the main verb of the sentence: Reduald rex Orientalium Anglorum is the subject of *obtinuit*. And its object cannot be other than *ducatum*, the leadership. (Unless it is treated as intransitive??!!)
3. As for **praebebat**, I feel inclined to think that the subject is also R, sharing the object with the main sentence (which is a strange alternative, yet the most plausible to me). That is the best I can do with the nouns's cases. I think some of the [meanings](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpraebeo) of the verb are consistent with R not having power yet, meaning that he was *pursuing* or *claiming* such power at the time Æ was alive.
4. Regarding the most-contentious ***eidem suae genti***, I see it as separate complements: R was holding forth power *to Æthelberht* (eidem), *for* [the sake of] *his people/clan* (suae genti). I think this reading is more likely than willing to give power *to the people* in the historical context.

I am still not 100% convinced of this. Either due to my own incomplete knowledge or (maybe?) the author's ambiguity (or both? Clearly I'm not the one to certify that). A good translation is beyond my knowledge of English, but I'll try my best:

*quartus Reduald rex Orientalium Anglorum, qui etiam uiuente Aedilbercto eidem suae genti ducatum praebebat, obtinuit;*

> Fourth, Redwald, king of the Eastern Angles, who obtained for his clan the leadership he was claiming from Æthelberht while he (the later, i.e. Æthelberht) was still alive.

Comment: I think the whole passage Nathaniel quotes is one huge sentence. There is a list of subjects, different kings, separated by semicolons. They all share the same predicate *obtinuit*. However, this explanation admittedly (which I only now realize!) has the weak point that the list continues after Reduald. Hmm... (I made some small grammar edits to your answer. Feel free to roll back or re-edit.)

Comment: I see it just as a list of kings, separated by semicolons. The fourth one happens to have a relative clause needing a full sentence. I don't see a contradiction for _obtinuit_ to be linked to Redwald only.

Comment: The beginning "*Nam primus imperium huiusmodi Aelli rex Australium Saxonum*" does not have a predicate if the sentence terminates at the semicolon. The predicate could semantically well be *obtinuit*, but it comes so much later that I'm inclined to believe that the kings in between are all intended as subjects. This is why I find having Reduald as the only subject unlikely. The listed subjects can well come with relative clauses. The passage is tricky and ambiguous, so I can't say I'm sure of anything, though.

Comment: Remember that in Latin you can sometimes omit the verb: the first leader was Aellus, the second one was Caelin, the third one was Aedilberct, the fourth one Redwald, etc. Maybe my mother language is biasing me, but I see the semicolons as pretty clear separators in an enumeration. Besides, why would _obtinuit_ be in such a weird location? Which would be its singular subject?

Comment: It is not uncommon to omit *esse*, but the sentence has an accusative object (*imperium*) requiring a transitive predicate. Use of punctuation was not always the same it is today. With this in mind, I mentally modernize the semicolons into commas. For some reason I find "*Imperium primus Aelli, secundus Caelin, tertius Aedilberct, quartus Reduald obtinuit.*" quite natural elliptic structure. That said, I just want us to understand each other's readings, not argue that mine is any better.

Comment: Hahaha, ok, sorry. I naturally tend to feel the urge to defend my point when questioned. I also find strange -though not totally wrong- to omit a verb other than _esse_. Another possible explanation is Imperium is treated as _leader_ rather than _leadership_: there is [_some_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dimperium) evidence of this being likely in L&S.

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad to see another answer to this: more food for thought. I had not even considered many of the possibilities you raise here, like two verbs sharing _ducatum_ as an object, and the dative meaning "for the sake of". I'm currently thinking that L&S might be a little misleading here, since they're focused on classical Latin, and that the best way to sort this out is to look specifically at other histories written around Bede's time, and especially elsewhere in Bede's own writing. Nailing down usage of _præbere_ in this kind of context might help a lot.

Comment: @BenKovitz, the more I think about it, the more I like the _shared object_: I can think of a couple of constructions in romance languages where an object is shared by more than one verb. In turn, it doesn't sound wrong to me at all to omit an _illum_ when unambiguous, although I admit it needs more evidence to be affirmed with certainty.