# How can you best teach possessive pronouns to English-speaking students?

Tags: syntax, pronouns, english, pedagogy

## Background

Latin and Germanic languages such as German, Norwegian, Danish, Swedish, and probably several more, have a specific word to denote possession: As Latin says *suus, sua, suum*, I as a Norwegian can say *sin, si, sitt*. Similarly, as Latin has *ejus, ejus, ejus*, I as a Norwegian can say *hans, hennes, dens/dets*. English lacks the first one. We can add ‘own’ or ‘self’ to emphasise the pronouns his, her, its, but I fear the distinction might still be lost on many students.

Some example sentences from our discussion at [Conloqvivm](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61871132#61871132):

- Vi så ham lufte hunden sin
- We saw him walk (‘air’) his dog.
- * Wir sahen ihn seinen Hund gehen.

  - However, German possessives work the same as in English, and thus the correct German translation would be ‘Wir sahen ihn mit seinem Hund spazieren (gehen)’.
- * Eum vidēbāmus canem suum ambulāre.

  - However, ambulāre can only be made transitive with objects of place, so the correct Latin here would be ‘Vidēbāmus eum cum cane suō ambulantem’ Maybe *Eum vidēbāmus canem suum vādere* works?

*Corrections to my translations are much appreciated; I am still learning. Thank you to Dario for these corrections*

Rewriting this to use the same gender of the subject and the logical subject, further emphasises the difference between English and these other languages:

- Norwegian

  - Han¹ så ham² lufte hunden hans¹.
  - Han¹ så ham² lufte hunden sin².
    *Note that I corrected the numbers on this one from my Conloqvivm example.*
- Latin

  - Is¹ eum² vidēbat canem ejus¹ ambulāre.
  - Is¹ eum² vidēbat canem suum² ambulāre.
- English

  - He¹ saw him² walk his[¹ ²] dog.

Unlike English, there is no need for a rewrite to clearly communicate who is doing what. That is at the core of my question, which I will arrive at at the end.

## Grammars and grammarians

Some grammar comments might also be in order:

- Eitrem § 28 mentions that the possessive pronouns (*meus, mea meum; tuus, tua, tuum; suus, sua, suum; noster, nostra, nostrum; vester, vestra, vestrum*) are used as adjectives and declined as per *longus* and *pulcher*. He also mentions that they often must be translated as *hans/hennes/dens/dets/deres* (his/her/its/its/their). They are strenghened/stressed by adding *‑met* and *‑pte*.
- Eitrem § 115 further emphasises that both personal pronouns and possessive pronouns are used ‘*berre* når dei har eit visst ettertrykk, ved motsetnad eller for å gjere meininga tydeleg’ ‘og bare når disse pronomenene står som subjekt.’ (‘only when have a certain secondary stressing, with negation or for sake of clarity’ ‘and only when these pronouns are subjects’).
- Eitrem § 116, which is specifically about the reflexives *sē* and *sēsē*, adds the following:

  - ‘Det refleksive pronoment *se* og det refleksive eigedomspronomenet *suus* viser til subjektet i same setning (direkte refleksiv). Men dei kan også vise til andre setningsledd (objekt eller indirekte objekt)’ (‘The reflective pronoun *sē* and the reflective possessive pronoun *sēsē* points to the subject in the same sentence (directly reflective). But they can also point to other parts of the sentence (object or indirect object)’).
  - ‘*Se* og *suus* i ei **bisetning** (leddsetning) kan vise til subjektet i hovudsetninga når bisetninga er noko som er sagt eller tenkt av subjektet (indirekte refleksiv) […] På same måte er det i **akkusativ med infinitiv**’. (‘*Sē* and *suus* in a subordinate clause can point to the subject in the main clause when the subordinate clause is something said or thought by the subject (indirectly reflexive) […] It is the same way with *accusative with infinitive*’.)
- Nils Sjöstrand § 63 has the same description as E.28, including the remark about adding *‑met* or *‑pte*.
- Nils Sjöstrand § 160, further elaborates that ‘De reflexiva pronomina **se** och **suus** ha en mera omfattande syftning än de svenska reflexivpronomina **sig** och **sin**.’ (‘The reflexive pronouns *sē* and *suus* have a more comprehensive usage than the Swedish reflexive pronouns *sig* and *sin*.’)

He lists several examples of Latin using the reflexive/possessive pronoun where Swedish (and as far as I can tell Norwegian too) would use a possessive determinative. Examples from NS:

- Honestātem ipsam per *sē* nōn amātis – Ni älska inte hedern i och för *sig* (You did not love honour in and of it*self*).
- Caesar Fabium cum suā legiōne remittit – Caesar sände tillbaka Fabius med *hans egen* legion (Caesar sent Fabius back with *his own* legion).

## Question

As this makes clear, the possessive pronoun has more usage in Latin than it does in English and in the other Germanic languages as well. But whereas I, from my own experience, remember there not being many questions about when and how to use this in the classroom when we were taught this in Norway, I found that my English-speaking students found the usage of suus/sua/suum to be much more difficult to understand. My best explanation so far, has been that it can be translated as pronoun plus self or pronoun plus own: himself, her own.

This only gets us some of the way though. Thus my question: What are good approaches to teaching the usage of the Latin *sē* and *suus, sua, suum* to students whose mother tongue is English? Might there be some links to Old or Middle English that could prove useful?

Comment: Relevant: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1309/how-to-resolve-ambiguity-with-reflexive-pronouns

Comment: In (at least some) Slavonic languages these "reflexive possessive pronouns are used in first and second person as well as third, i.e. if I am reading my book, it is "svoju knigu" in Russian rather than "moju knigu".

Comment: So almost like saying _\*mesuum librum legō_?

Comment: No, more like saying _suum librum legō_

Comment: 1) Colloquial German (and Dutch, as pointed out by Cerberus in Conloqvivm) works like English, not Norwegian. GER _sein_ is like ENG _his,_  not like NOR _sin,_ despite the similarity. 2) A correct German translation of your example would be _Wir sahen ihn mit seinem Hund spazieren (gehen):_ the verb _gehen_ is intransitive. 3) Similarly, _ambulō_ can only be made transitive with objects of place, as in _ambulō iter_ ( = **to walk a path**). _Ambulo canem_ is impossible. _Educo canem ambulatum_ would be possible, but my translation is _vidimus/videbamus eum cum cane suo ambulantem_

Comment: @Dario Thank you for this feedback. The German I was not aware of at all. The Latin: My dictionary agrees then with what you say, with the following entry (translated: ‘**ambulō,** _1. walk up and down, around, stroll; travel, march;_ fessus a-ndo; in sole, in litore a.; bene a-a: (safe travels! good luck on your journey!), Pt.; Caesar eo modo a-t ut _marches; w._ object: maria a-avit Xerxes, terram navigavit, Ov.’ The sole example of object does use an object of place. Perhaps vādō can do the job?

Comment: @Dario I forgot to mention you in the above edit, so allow me to make mention of your contribution here in the comments.